# Downloads elementary os

Tags: download

I bought your operating system today, but I can not download it. I suggest downloading directly from the server or via a magnet-link. No way works, nothing is downloaded. Tried different browsers and nothing happens. At purchase used the following e-mail address: mk.td@mail.ru

Answer (score 2):

If you depends on time you put "0" in other amount field and download elementaryOS. Of course you checked youe bank account if elementary.io collected money?